# How to use google-api-nodejs-client to get a list of group members

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-cloud-functions, google-api-nodejs-client

### Goal

Use `googleapis` to get a list of group members. [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/get) show this:

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/groupKey/members`

### Question

How is this done with `directory.groups.get` , `.hasMembers`, or other? I'm not sure how or where to add members to the request.

```
directory.groups.get({
    auth: jwtClient,
    domain: "mydomain.com",
    groupKey: "mygroup@mydomain.com",
},
```

### What Works

Here I get information about membership, but not the list of members

```
exports.getGroupsMemberships = function (jwtClient) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        jwtClient.authorize(err => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve();
        });
    }).then(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            directory.groups.get({
                auth: jwtClient,
                domain: "mydomain.com",
                groupKey: "mygroup@mydomain.com",
            },
            function (err, resp) {
                if (err) reject(err);
                else resolve(resp);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

*which returns*

```
  "gsuiteGroupsMemberships : { kind: 'admin#directory#group',
  id: 'xxx...222',
  etag: '"TN3...Dw"',
  email: 'mygroup@mydomain.com',
  name: 'My Group',
  directMembersCount: '3',
  description: 'Use this email group to contact My Group.',
  adminCreated: false,
  nonEditableAliases: [ 'mygroup@mydomain.com.test-google-a.com' ] }"
```

When I use *[Try This API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/get#try-it)* in the browswer, I do get the list of members, i.e. emails, role, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you use the list from the `members` resource, not the `groups`.

```
exports.getGroupsMemberships = function (jwtClient) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        jwtClient.authorize(err => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve();
        });
    }).then(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            directory.members.list({
                auth: jwtClient,
                groupKey: "mygroup@mydomain.com",
            },
            function (err, resp) {
                if (err) reject(err);
                else resolve(resp);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

If you want both the group metadata *and* the member list you'll need to make two calls:

```
exports.getGroupDataAndMembers = function (jwtClient) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        jwtClient.authorize(err => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve();
        });
    }).then(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            directory.groups.get({
                auth: jwtClient,
                domain: "mydomain.com",
                groupKey: "mygroup@mydomain.com",
            },
            function (err, resp) {
                if (err) reject(err);
                else resolve(resp);
            });
        });
    }).then((groupMetaCall) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            directory.members.list({
                auth: jwtClient,
                groupKey: "mygroup@mydomain.com",
            },
            function (err, resp) {
                if (err) reject(err);
                else {
                    groupMetaCall.data.members = resp.data.members;
                    resolve(groupMetaCall);
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

The Try this API that you provided is for the get endpoint of the members resource. It returns the information about *a* member of a group.

Here is the documentation for the members.list:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list